# How to remove duplicates in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, duplicates

I have a large file with a bunch of movie data, including a unique ID for each movie. although every ID on each line is unique, some lines include duplicate movie data.

For example:

```
ID,movie_title,year
1,toy story,1995
2,jumanji,1995
[...]
6676,toy story,1995
6677,jumanji,1995
```

In this case, I'd like to remove completly the `6677,toy story,1995` and `6677,jumanji,1995` lines. This occurs with more than just one movie, so I can't do a simple find and replace. I've tried to use Sublime Text's `Edit>Permute Lines>Unique` feature and it works fine, but I end up losing the first column of the data (the unique IDs).

can anyone recommend a better way to get rid of these duplicate lines?

Comment: Which tools can you use ? On which platform are you working ? Is this a one-time job or will that sort of task occur repeatedly ?

Comment: @collapsar I'm on OS X, I'll use any tool that will get the task done (bash/python/OS X's numbers/whatever) as this is a one-time job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following perl script does the trick. Effectively, all occurrences of a movie  but the first will be deleted from the list of entries. Do not forget to add the file paths. Execute with 'perl ' from the command line (mac os ships with perl):

```
use IO::File;

my (
      $curline
    , $fh_in
    , $fh_out
    , $dict
    , @fields
    , $key
    , $value
);

$fh_in  = new IO::File("<..."); # add input file name
$fh_out = new IO::File(">..."); # add output file name
while (<$fh_in>) {
    chomp;
    $curline = $_;
    @fields = split ( /,/, $curline );
    ($key, $value) = (join(',', @fields[1..$#fields]), $fields[0]);
    if (!exists($$dict{$key})) {
        $$dict{$key} = 1;
        $fh_out->print("$curline\n");
    }
}
$fh_out->close();
exit(0);
```

**Explanation**

- The code processes the input line by line
- It maintains an hash of movie identifiers seen.
- Movie identifiers are defined as the line content without the id number and the immediately following comma.
- A line is printed iff the movie identifier has not yet been seen.

**Caveat**

- Evidently, this solution is not robust against spelling errors.
- A certain degree of error tolerance can be added by normalizing keys. Example (case-insensitive matching):

  ```
  my $key_norm; # move that out of the loop in production code
  $key_norm = lc($key);        
  if (!exists($$dict{$key_norm})) {
     $$dict{$key_norm} = 1;
     $fh_out->print("$curline\n");
  }
  ```
- Neither elegance nor performance had a say in authoring this code ;-)